# Implement CDCN using tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Recently, I want to implement CDCN in CVPR2020 using tensorflow2.8 + python3.9. This requires my custom layer acquire current conv2d layer's weight.
However, when I try to add my custom layer to the sequential model, error occurred:NotImplementedError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled.
This is my code. Can anyone helps me? I have tried to add tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution(), but it doesn't work.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras as tfk
import tensorflow as tf


class CDC(tfk.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation=None, theta=0.7, **kwargs):
        super(CDC, self).__init__()
        self.theta = theta
        self.activation = None
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.padding = padding
        if activation is not None:
            self.activation = tfk.activations.get(activation)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.conv = tfk.layers.Conv2D(self.output_dim, self.kernel_size, padding=self.padding, input_shape=input_shape)
        self.conv.build(input_shape=input_shape)
        self._kernel = self.conv.kernel
        super(CDC, self).build(input_shape)
        self.built = True


    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        vanillaOutput = self.conv(inputs)
        weightSum = self.conv.kernel.numpy().sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0)
        weightSum = np.reshape(weightSum, (1, 1, 1, self.output_dim))
        weightSum = tf.constant(weightSum, dtype=tf.float32)
        cDiff = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, filters=weightSum, strides=self.conv.strides, padding=self.conv.padding.upper())
        result = vanillaOutput - self.theta * cDiff
        if self.activation is not None:
            return self.activation(result)
        return vanillaOutput
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the sum of all elements in kernel

```
tf.math.reduce_sum()
```

Also replace the lines

```
weightSum = self.conv.kernel.numpy().sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0)
weightSum = np.reshape(weightSum, (1, 1, 1, self.output_dim))
weightSum = tf.constant(weightSum, dtype=tf.float32)
```

...

```
weightSum = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.reduce_sum(self.conv.kernel,axis=0),axis=0),axis=0)
weightSum = tf.reshape(weightSum, (1, 1, 1, self.output_dim))
```